# Why does Nambu-Goto action need parametrization but Einstein-Hilbert action does not?

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, string-theory, integration

In the following book (page 19 / equation 2.7 --- part of the free preview at [google-books](https://books.google.ca/books/about/String_Theory_and_M_Theory.html?id=WgUkSTJWQacC&printsec=frontcover&source=kp_read_button&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false)), we have the parametrization general volume element, defined as

$$
d\mu_p=\sqrt{-\det G_{\alpha\beta}}d^{p+1}\sigma
$$

where

$$
G_{\alpha\beta}=g_{\mu\nu}(X)\partial_\alpha X^\mu\partial _\beta X^\nu
$$

---

For instance, if $p=0$, then taking the parametrization $\alpha,\beta$ to be $\tau,\tau$ we get:

$$
G_{\tau\tau}=\pmatrix{g_{\mu\nu}\partial_\tau X^\mu \partial_\tau X^\nu} \implies d\mu_p=\sqrt{-g_{\mu\nu}\partial_\tau X^\mu \partial_\tau X^\nu} d\tau
$$

which is the arclength.

---

As a second example, if p=1 then taking the parametrization $\alpha,\beta$ to be $\sigma,\tau$, we get:

$$
G_{\sigma\tau}=\pmatrix{
g_{\mu\nu}\partial_\tau X^\mu \partial_\tau X^\nu && 
g_{\mu\nu} \partial_\tau X^\mu \partial_\sigma X^\nu\\
g_{\mu\nu} \partial_\sigma X^\mu \partial_\tau X^\nu &&
g_{\mu\nu} \partial_\sigma X^\mu \partial_\sigma X^\nu
}
$$

Then, if we take $g_{\mu\nu}$ to be flat Minkowski space-time, we get the Nambu-Goto action:

$$
d\mu_p=\sqrt{-\det G_{\sigma\tau}}d\sigma\ d\tau=\sqrt{(\partial_\tau X^\mu \partial_\sigma X^\nu)(\partial_\sigma X^\mu \partial_\tau X^\nu)-(\partial_\tau X^\mu \partial_\tau X^\nu)(\partial_\sigma X^\mu \partial_\sigma X^\nu)}d \sigma d \tau
$$

---

For instance in general relativity (p=3), I can recover the volume element using

$$
G_{xyzt} = \pmatrix{g_{\mu\nu}\partial_t X^\mu \partial_t X^\nu \dots \\
\vdots & \ddots\\
&&&g_{\mu\nu}\partial_z X^\mu \partial_z X^\nu
}
$$

But if I chose a parametrization such that $\partial_\alpha X^\mu=1,\partial_\alpha X^\nu=1,\partial_\beta X^\mu=1$ and $\partial_\beta X^\nu=1$ then I get:

$$
G_{\alpha\beta}=g_{\mu\nu}
$$

And consequently, the volume element is the same as that used in the Einstein-Hilbert action:

$$
d\mu_p = \sqrt{-\det G_{xyzt} }dxdydzdt = \sqrt{-\det g_{\mu\nu}}dxdydzdt \tag{1}
$$

***My first question is why is parametrization not relevant for general relativity. What is the difference between a 3-brane in 4D spacetime and just 4D spacetime (both integrate over 4 variables)?***

---

My second question is related to the previous one by for area. Why is parametrization neglected in the area-tensor definition (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_tensor#Area).

According to the link the area connects to the metric tensor as follows:

$$
A=\iint \sqrt{\det g_{\mu\nu}} dudv \tag{2}
$$

Which is obtained, here also, by posing $G_{uv}=g_{\mu\nu}$.

***Why is here the parametrization of the surface not important, but important in the general case?***

Why are both the 4-volume element and the 2-volume element not require parametrization - what is special about their construction that they can get away with less than the general case of $G_{\alpha\beta}$?

Comment: Parametrization invariance is the equivalent of diffeomorphism invariance in GR.

Comment: Parametrization? Do you mean coordinates? Both NG and EH are coordinate invariant geometric invariants, and both can be written in terms of integrals over coordinate ranges.

Comment: @Prof.Legolasov The core of my question is; the Nambu-Goto has derivatives under the square root, and GR doesn't. I do not understand why that is. Why does GR not need to be expressed as a parametrized 4-surface in 4-d spacetime, whereas Nambu-Goto needs to expressed as a parametrized 2-surface in 4-d spacetime?